# C++/CLI wrapper for native C++ dll

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I have written an C++/Cli wrapper for a native C++ dll, but when I call some method from C# I get an System.AccessViolationException error in my C++/Cli Wrapper dll! It's necessary to marshal the unmanaged types or something else?!

```
// Wrapper.h

typedef UnmanagedClass* (*Instance)(void);

private:
    UnmanagedClass *m_object; // unmanaged object   

// Wrapper.cpp

Wrapper:Wrapper()
{
    HINSTANCE unmanagedLib;
    unmangedLib = LoadLibrary(SystemStringToLPCSTR(dllPath+dllName));

    // load instance
    Instance _createInstance = (Instance)GetProcAddress(unmangedLib, "GetInstance");
    m_object = (_createInstance)(); 
}

Wrapper::~Wrapper()
{
    m_object->~UnmanagedClass();
}


Uint32 Wrapper::SomeMethod(Uint8 *bytRecvBuffer, int &iRecvLen)
{
    return m_object->SomeMethod(bytRecvBuffer, iRecvLen);
}

// Unmanaged Class

class UnmanagedClass    
{
public:
    /**
    * Default constructor. 
    */
    UnmanagedClass(void);
    /**
    * Default Destructor
    */
    ~UnmanagedClass(void);

    virtual Uint32 Wrapper::SomeMethod(Uint8 *bytRecvBuffer, int &iRecvLen);
};

// export the UnmanagedClass object
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) UnmanagedClass* GetInstance();

// UnamangedClass.cpp

UnamangedClass::~UnamangedClass(void)
{
    if (UnamangedClassDLL != NULL)
        FreeLibrary(UnamangedClassDLL);

    UnamangedClassDLL = NULL;
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) UnmanagedClass* GetInstance()
{

    return new UnmanagedClass();
}
```

When I call at example SomeMethod from C# I get the error in C++/Cli dll!
(I included the C++/cli dll with add reference in C sharp project and create the Wrapper object)

Thank you for your help!

greets

Comment: `It's necessary to marshal the unmanaged types or something else?` How can we possibly know when you don't show the definitions of `UnmanagedClass` or `Wrapper`? (BTW, `m_object->~UnmanagedClass();` looks absolutely wrong.)

Comment: I don't think this is wrong (read it here http://ondotnet.com/lpt/a/4731 -> I write the wrapper with this tutorial)

Comment: @leon22 : Again, we can't know that for sure since we can't see the definitions of `UnmanagedClass` and `Wrapper`.

Comment: You see the definitions of Wrapper class

Comment: @leon22 : What is the implementation of `GetInstance`? Specifically, how does it allocate and construct an `UnmanagedClass` instance in a manner that you would think it appropriate to call its destructor directly and then not actually deallocate any memory?

Comment: @leon22 : Yes, thank you, but not enough just yet. :-] What is the implementation of `GetInstance`?

Comment: I thought you will ask (now I added it) ;-)

Comment: Dont this access violetion exception has an InnerException?
Is your .dll is in some loadable location? If it is custom dll try to put it to the execution directory.

Comment: @MajesticRa: I have checked this (the dll will loaded normally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error (System.AccessViolationException):

I'm using an other object in the unmanaged code without initialization (null object -> only declared)!

Init the object with new() and all should run properly!

Answer (score 2):

It is inappropriate to directly call the destructor of an object that was allocated with (non-placement) `new`. Try changing

```
m_object->~UnmanagedClass();
```

to

```
delete m_object;
m_object = 0;
```

(`m_object = 0;` is necessary because unlike a native C++ type's destructor, which may only be called once, an managed type's `Dispose` implementation may be called repeatedly, and doing so must have defined behavior.)

Or, better yet, in addition to exposing a `GetInstance` function, also expose a `DestroyInstance` function and call that instead of using `delete` so that consuming code does not need to depend on the implementation details of `GetInstance` (i.e., that it allocates its instance using `operator new`).

Comment: Thank you, but why I will get an System.AccessViolationException exception when calling a method?

Comment: @leon22 : See if making the change helps before I type out the response to that. ;-]

Comment: I don't think so, because I don't call the destructor: m_object->SomeMethod() (but you are right its a better way to destruct the object)

Comment: OK. As I supposed nothing changed! Any other suggestions?!

Comment: Have nobody an other suggestion?! Thanks

Comment: Ok I have tested it with an easy method (double DoDouble(double number) and it works! 

At this point I think I must marshal the parameters of SomeMethod (Uint8 *bytRecvBuffer and int &iRecvLen)?!


How can I do it in my C++/Cli dll???


Thanks and greets

Comment: @leon22 : I can only answer that concretely if you show the implementation of `UnmanagedClass::SomeMethod`, especially if/how it allocates memory.

Comment: Ok. An other point: it's possible in VS 2008 to debug also to the unmanaged dll (to see where the error occurs). At the moment I added only an reference in my C sharp project to the managed C++/Cli dll!